# Passing a string(or any other argument) into a QWidget constructor

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QMainWindow that has a bunch of images displayed, using pixmapped Qlabels. Clicking on any of the images should pop up a QDialog.

The problem is that is a way I can pass an argument, say a string, into the constructor of a a QDialog? I want to then use that string to populate labels in the QDialog.

Comment: Something sounds wrong in the question.. can you provide more information and post some code? I don't see why you would need to pass a QString to the dialog if you can access the labels in your QMainWindow.

Comment: @nbilal Sure, the QMainWindow is connected to the database where I store the urls for the QLabel images. 

I want the QDialog to be able to get information from the database based on which QLabel is clicked. 

The easiest way I thought to do that was to pass the url as a QString to the QDialog, search the database for the url and populate the QDialog with other information in the database.

Hope this makes sense

Comment: It is still not clear if you actually have a subclass of QDialog and where you are populating the QDialog with information ..

Comment: @nbilal yup. subclassed QDialog. To store the information, I'm going to use QLabels

Comment: Ok well there is no issue then? just pass the QString as suggested below.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a subclass of QDialog and implement your own constructor.

```
class QDialogPopup : public QDialog
{
   Q_OBJECT
public :
   virtual ~QDialogPopup();
   QDialogPopup(std::string labelString);
}
```

Comment: In this case, you want a QString, not a std::string to avoid conversion overhead (since the QLabel you'll pass it to has a QString argument in setText(). Also, the string should be passed by const reference, to avoid the cost of a copy.

Comment: My fault, @tmcguire is right, you´ll need to use a QString and to avoid overhead use const ref.